# Find all the solutions of $x^2+7=2^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Checking for some small natural numbers $n$, I found out that $2^n-7$ is a perfect square for $n=3,4,5,7,15$. How can we find all of the numbers $n$ for which $2^n-7$ is a perfect square?
 
What I tried: For $n=1,2$ there is no $x$ to satisfy the equality. For $n=3$ we have an answer $x=1$ so suppose $n>3$. If $n>3$ then $8|2^n$ so $2^n\equiv0\bmod8$.
 We also know that for every $x$, $x^2\equiv0,1,4\bmod 8$. so $x^2+7\equiv 7,0,3\bmod8$ and we had $x^2+7=2^n$ so $x^2+7\equiv0\bmod8$ and this only holds when $x\equiv 3,5\bmod8$.
 So the answers for $n>3$ should all be on the form of: $x=8m\pm3$. We can also say: $x^2+7=2^n$ so $x^2-1=2^n-8=8(2^{n-3}-1)$ so $(x-1)(x+1)=8(2^{n-3}-1)$.
 I don't know where to go from here. I would appreciate any help.
Edit: Apparently this equation is called the **Ramanujan–Nagell equation**.  I found [this](http://buzzard.ups.edu/courses/2013spring/projects/spencer-ant-ups-434-2013.pdf) pdf in another question but I can't understand it. I would appreciate a good elementary proof (if there is any).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437640/ramanujan-nagell-theorem-proof-question and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185458/for-what-values-of-n-is-n2n2-a-power-of-2

Comment: Thank you, i noted that in my question.

Comment: if $n$ is even you can easily see that we must have finitelly many solutions as $x^2+7=y^2$ has

Comment: You noted there was another question. You didn't note which question. I did.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is $2^n -7$ a perfect square?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126527). Note that [it is accepted to mark the older question as a duplicate of the newer one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16417).

Comment: I saw this exact question, as well as the answer to it (which is now embedded in the question itself), about 10 minutes ago!!!