# When is $2^n -7$ a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

This came up while solving another ENT problem. I want to ask when is: $$2^n -7 \text{ where } n\geq 3$$ a perfect square? Specifically, I also wanted to know what would be the solutions when $n$ is odd? How should I solve this?

I can check that $n=3, 4, 7$ are solutions but cannot find more. As it is of the form $4k+1$, it doesn't help as well.

Comment: You might as well add $n=4$ to the list because it's easy to show that's the last time it's happening for an even number.

Comment: Works for n in {3, 4, 5, 7, 15} and possibly more

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605311), but it appears that this question has been received much more positively... Better make the other question a duplicate of this one -> I've voted to do so.

Comment: @barto Heh :D  ${}$

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The equation $$2^n-7=x^2$$ is called the [Ramanujan–Nagell equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation). It has been conjectured by Ramanujan and proven by Nagell, and later others, that the only solutions are $n=3,4,5,7$ and $15$. Here are two proofs:

- [one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.6928v2.pdf) originally due to Hasse
- [another](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2323504?sid=21105743030713&uid=4&uid=3737864&uid=2) by Wells Johnson

I believe all proofs make use of unique factorization in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$.

Answer (score 1):

So, there were just a few solutions to $2^n = x^2 + 7.$

The other side is, for $n \geq 3,$ there is always a solution to
$$ 2^n = x^2 + 7 y^2  $$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1.$ Proof by induction; as I recall, to keep the gcd thing, we demand that $x \equiv y \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ for all $n,$ which sometimes requires $x$ or $y$ or both to be negative. Note that it would not be impressive if we allowed $x,y$ even, because doubling both $x,y$ just adds $2$ to $n.$

I'm just saying.