# Triangle numbers that are almost powers of two

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

### Question

Find all $n$ such that $\frac{n(n + 1)}{2} = 2^k - 1$ for some $k \ge 0$

### What I have Tried

So far I've plugged in some small values for $n$, and it works for $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 5\}$ (producing $\{0, 1, 3, 15\}$.

Then I tried letting a computer do it, and found $90$ gives an almost power of two, $4095$. I've tried brute-forcing $n$ up to $50\,000\,000$ but found no more answers.

Comment: I think you meant $n(n+1)/2$, otherwise your examples don't work.

Comment: This is a classical problem conjectured by Ramanujan and solved by Nagell.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437640/ramanujan-nagell-theorem-proof-question (there is a trivial reduction from this problem to the form of the equation discussed there).

Comment: @B.Mehta Thanks, I've changed it from a - to a + as it should have been.

Comment: @ErickWong The problem name (and link) are extremely helpful, thank you. Could you give me a hint on how to begin the reduction?

Comment: @spyr03 Hint: Start by multiplying both sides of your equation by $8$, then complete the square.